# localStorage should expire after 24 hours

Tags: javascript, cache, browser-storage

The following code is checking if the user's browser is IE and if this is the case and there's no localStorage yet, it sets a localStorage, which should be valid for only 24 hours.

```
(function ieAlert () {
  var isIE = document.documentMode
  var lastClear = window.localStorage.getItem('myLocalStorage')
  var timeNow = (new Date()).getTime()

  if (!isIE && lastClear === null) {
    window.alert(ieWarningText)
    // Setting a localStorage with 1 day expiry date
    if ((timeNow - lastClear) > 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) {
      window.localStorage.clear()
      window.localStorage.setItem('myLocalStorage', timeNow)
    }
  }
})()
```

How could the script be improved?

Comment: Might need more context on this one. Why do you need to clear the localStorage?

Comment: I just thought I need to clear the old localStorage after 24 hours and set a new one. Don't I need to clear it?

Comment: Your function does not make any sense. You check if `lastClear === null` then you subtract it (null) from the time. Thus the test `(timeNow - lastClear) > 8.64e7` will always pass (well apart from the first day of 1970)  as `null` will be coerced to 0